# How to make a drone apple picker

Tags: control-engineering, adaptive-control

I want to make a drone system which can recognise when fruit has dropped in our orchard, and pick it up and put it in a basket before theyve rotted on the lawn. I'm thinking buy a drone off amazon, attach some sensors, a camera and some fruit grabbers to it and bastardise the remote with a microcontroller and receivers, so falling fruit is recognised, and the drone can guide itself to pick it up. I was wondering if anyone could help in any way with the 2 bits (large bits I admit!) I don't yet know how to do:

1: how to recognise fallen/falling fruit

- I was thinking an image recognition system using a pi?

2: how to have the drone fly itself to pick it up and return it to a predefined location

- no idea yet besides accelerometers... Do I need to read up on missile guidance systems lol?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Missile guidance systems... well, might save you a lot of coding.

Comment: Apple recognition is a job for machine learning. Lots of info on the web.

Comment: Machine learning would be impressive in a drone!

Comment: Flying a drone autonomously close to the ground in an environment full of tree trunks sounds over-complicated, compared with a robot on the ground. If your apple recognition system tries to pick a apple that is still on the tree, that could be an "interesting" failure mode!

Comment: @alephzero Maybe he could program it only to pick up the apple if the background is grassy green. Oliver, do you know how to manage image recognition code? I sure don't.

Comment: Oh, and make sure your drone can lift both the raspberry and the apple. Good luck; I'd love to see it work!

Comment: Couldn't you just put some nets under the trees? I will admit I'm not familiar with commercial apple farming but it sounds like you'd need an army of drones and charging stations.

Comment: @palbitt no I've never used it, but there's always a first time

Comment: @jko the problem is the fruit starts going bad the second it falls. Also we don't want netting everywhere, we have  dogs!

Comment: @alephzero good points - we have steps to the orchard hence why I wanted a drone, but perhaps an rc lorry is more manageable!

Comment: @palbitt the fruit isn't necessarily non-green unfortunately

Comment: @jko it's not a big orchard, bout 1 acre

Comment: @OliverWalters Well... OpenCV has "canny edge detection." (https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) Maybe the camera could be angled toward the lawn, and OpenCV could highlight the apple shape for the neural net to process? Try converting the edge object to a Numpy array, then running it through one of those neural net packages.

Comment: @palbitt thanks, that's a great link, Ill investigate your idea - I was thinking though, maybe it would be easier to have something always looking for an object moving straight down in the image?

Comment: @OliverWalters That might work. The drone would have to be aimed at the apple, though.